# Kafka java consumer freezes after rebalance failure

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

we experienced an annoying Kafka consumer problem after a failure in consumer rebalancing. 
It seems we had network issues at a given time which caused a ZK session expiration.  This triggered a re-registration of the consumers and then a rebalancing.
The rebalancing failed after 4 tries (rebalance.retries.max=4).
On the consumer client sides (Java Kafka Consumers), we did not receive any notification of the pb. We were just not getting any new message, and the clients were running several hours without reading any message.

Is there a way to get notified in the consumers for such rebalancing failures, so that we can monitor and maybe restart our consumers?

Comment: This topic has been already answered

[Refer this link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775087/kafka-single-consumer-failure-in-a-group